# How to modify x axis distance in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I wonder, can x axis distance in gnuplot be modified?

For example, I have a datum with x = 10 and another datum x = 1000
In this case, the datum with x 10 will be so small compared to the x = 1000 and people will not be able to see the small datum clearly.

Therefore, I want to modify the distance in x axis like this:
a third part axis for x 10,
a third part axis for x 100,
a third part axis for x 1000

Or let's say that x axis length = 12 cm, I want to give 4cm to x = 10, 4cm to x = 100, and 4cm to x = 1000...

I hope my question is clear enough.. thanks!

Comment: Are you asking if you can modify `steps/tics` on xrange?

Comment: Use a logarithmic scale with `set logscale x`

Comment: @msfoster no, modifying tics on x range will not change its scale..

Comment: @Christoph I have never used the logscale.. I guess I can try